# What is message structure/syntax for Bluetooth LE _commands_?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to understand how the following information translates in to a message to a BLE device from which I am trying to read some stored data.
The first part of the device documentation gives me base UUID and two services.

```
UUID Base: 1212-efde-1234-567feathf890 
Service UUID: 0x1462 
Characteristic: 0x1463 (write/notify)
```

That makes sense and I understand that to write to the device I send a message composed of the service/characteristic and the base UUID ie. 00001462-1212-efde-1234-567feathf890 and 00001463-1212-efde-1234-567feathf890 respectively.  With that characteristic I attach the payload that I want written.

However, to read the data the documentation specifies a ***command*** a portion of the docs for commands is:

```
Command:
Message Name: Read the storage data with index, part 1(time) 
Message ID: 0x36 
Message Description: Read data (part 1: date and time) 
Length:  Request: 8 bytes / Response: 8 bytes
```

I don't know how to interpret that.  I thought it meant that I needed to include 0x36 as the payload for the 'write' characteristic and that the device would respond with the data when that value was written but that doesn't seem to work.  What should the message to execute the command look like?

Note: I connect and disconnect to the device and my write messages don't throw any errors so I assume they are successful.  It's just that I can't access the data on the device (entered manually so yes, it's there).

Update:  While not explicitly stated, it's possible that the device uses serial over BLE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the documentation missed an important point.  The ble was being used to communicate serially formatted data.  Instead of using the GATT definitions the ble was writing and receiving data in UART serial format.  So a proper 'write' would use the service and characteristic with the data formatted as:

`<start byte> <command byte> <data byte(s)> <stop byte> <checksum>`

The received data would have the same format but the "< data byte(s) >" would obviously be different.  In each case the  would have to be decomposed to bits and parsed as appropriate.  It's a cool way to keep an embedded serial interface on device useful long after an upgrade to ble.